# Good casual gaming laptop

Tags: laptop, gaming

I'm looking for a decent laptop on which I can also play...I'm not really interested in super high graphics...but I would like to be able to play the latest games at 720p resolution with medium/high-ish settings. My budget is of 700 €.

So, I found this [Medion Erazer P6661](https://www.amazon.de/Medion-P6661-Notebook-GeForce-Betriebssystem/dp/B01GYZXS3K/ref=sr_1_1?ie=UTF8&qid=1469837099&sr=8-1&keywords=Medion%20P6661) which has pretty good specs, and is just at my budget limit, but I have been reading online about people having issues on Medion laptops and about them being build with cheap materials, and I myself have had a bad time on a Medion laptop, even though it was a really cheap one.

So, here's my question: ...is this laptop worth my money? And if not, what other laptops should I consider for that price?

The most important features to me are:
 - Skylake processor (i5 or i7)
 - At least 8 GB of RAM
 - 1 TB HDD
 - nVidia card (940m or better)
 - 17.3" screen would be preferred over 15.6", but I can't seem to find          many

Comment: Please give us more details about what you want in this laptop so your question can be reopened (e.g., number of USB ports, some kind of video port, size and weight preferences, etc.).